# Headgear of Ancient India

Tags: history, dharma-shastras, clothes

This is more a historical question, but I want religious ie dharmashastric text to answer this. What headgear did all people of ancient India wear and which ones were exclusive to the clergy (brahmins).

Comment: you may check this out  [Head Dress: Uṣṇīṣa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/history/essay/cosmetics-costumes-and-ornaments-in-ancient-india/d/doc1146457.html) ; [Head Dress: Veṣṭana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/history/essay/cosmetics-costumes-and-ornaments-in-ancient-india/d/doc1146458.html)

Comment: @Bingming what about the hood-like thing Advaitans usually are depicted of wearing?

Comment: I don't know what it's called. But it's not a compulsory part of their dress. It's similar to an avaguṇṭhana or ghūṅghaṭa.

Comment: @Bingming alrighty!